# How do I specify an encoding for TextCells in CellList?

Tags: gwt

I use a CellList like this

```
CellList<String> cellList = new CellList<String>(new TextCell());
```

and then give it an `ArrayList<String>`.

If a String contains an "ü" I get a question mark in the browser (FF4, GWT Dev Plugin). If I use `&uuml;` I get `&uuml;`

Where can I specify the encoding, so that "ü" works? (I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but the "ü" is currently hardcoded in the .java file and not read from somewhere else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GWT compiler assumes, that your Java files are encoded in UTF-8. Make sure, that your editor is set to save in that encoding.

You should also make sure to set the encoding of the HTML page to a unicode capable encoding like UTF-8 (this allows you to use even more exotic characters that you won't find in other charsets):

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   ...
```

Moreover, if you later want to retrieve the strings from a database, make sure, that it is also set up to handle Unicode, and that your JDBC driver connects in Unicode mode (required for some databases).